# how to demonstrate/test the change of variance along a continuous variable

Tags: r, variance

How could I test if the variance of a dependent variable (y) is changing with a continuous independent variable - like in the reprex. I would also like to quantify the strength of this relation somehow. Cutting x to chunks and calculating variance within the chunks seems arbitrary to me.

```
library(plyr)
df<-ldply(seq(1:500), function(x){c(x,runif(1,min=-x,max=x))})
plot(df$V1,df$V2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A common way in financial applications is to fit GARCH model. It produces time varying variance estimate which you can analyze and decide on whether variance is changing